# Compiling Error l3experimental: "kernel/command-already-defined"

Tags: errors, expl3

when compiling my project I get errors related to the l3experimental package.

From the log file:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3tl-build.sty"
Package: l3tl-build 2015/07/28 v5700 L3 Experimental token list construction


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \l__tl_build_start_index_int already defined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.65 \int_new:N \l__tl_build_start_index_int

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a coding error.
| 
| LaTeX has been asked to create a new control sequence
| '\l__tl_build_start_index_int' but this name has already been used
| elsewhere.
| 
| The current meaning is:
|   \count126
|...............................................

\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count305

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \l__tl_build_index_int already defined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.66 \int_new:N \l__tl_build_index_int

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a coding error.
| 
| LaTeX has been asked to create a new control sequence
| '\l__tl_build_index_int' but this name has already been used elsewhere.
| 
| The current meaning is:
|   \count127
|...............................................

\l__tl_build_index_int=\count306
```

and the same with a lot of other control sequences.
I am working on a min example where the error occurs.
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I can't check with my install right now, but `l3tl-build 2015/07/28` was a bit older than what I could find on the web. So maybe an update can help (make sure to update all packages!). If that does not help, we probably need to see an MWE.

Comment: Mhhh, it seems the package was removed from `l3experimental`. Not sure if it (or its functionality) moved elsewhere. I guess your best bet is a full update of all packages involved. If the functionality has moved then other packages should call the new commands, if things were removed they should refrain from calling anything.

Comment: The `l3tl-build` package was moved to the kernel.  Normally there is a transition period where the package just produces a warning, but here we made a mistake in the markup which means the file `l3tl-build.sty` is not generated at all.  Your installation has a stray file `l3tl-build.sty`.  A very short-term solution is to put an empty file `l3tl-build.sty` in the directory of your TeX file.

Comment: Fixed in the latest sources on Github.  https://github.com/latex3/latex3  Should make it to CTAN in a few days.

Comment: There is a good reason why `l3tl-build` was removed with no transition: it provides no user function!  Can you clarify which package was loading `l3tl-build` behind the hood so that we can discuss with the package author what interface they need?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I thing the problem comes with the media9 package.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `l3tl-build` package was moved to the kernel. Normally there is a transition period where the package just produces a warning, but we had not done that for this case (somewhat by mistake).  There is a good reason why `l3tl-build` was removed with no transition: it provides no user function!

Anyways, it's always better to have clearer error messages so now we generate a transitional `l3tl-build.sty` that produces an error.